# What is limit for the number of students for one supervisor in India?

Tags: advisor, supervision, india

How many number of students can be supervised by a supervisor in India? Is there a limit imposed by the government of India?

Comment: I recall an anecdote from a prof in my grad work. During his PhD he gave a talk to the department on his work. The Big Name Prof sat in the front row asking useful interesting questions and showing great interest. At the end of the talk, BNP stood up, shook his hand and said "That was a very good talk. Who is your supervisor?"  "You are Dr. BNP."  "Oh! Oh! Well come to my office tomorrow and we will talk about your work."

Comment: @puppetsock I have a similar story about a master student - at the thesis defense the professor allegedly entered the room and asked "I am the advisor or the chairman for this thing?". (He was the advisor.)

Comment: To those voting to close this as depending on individual factors, please keep in mind that we decided to [explicitly allow](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3896/7734) questions on regulations on the national level.

Comment: My supervisor is having 32 students under his belt to guide. Still he recruiting new research scholar.

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick search on this and I could find a document that suggests this:

> At any given point of time, the maximum number of Ph.D. students allowed should not exceed 8 students for a recognized Professor, 6 students for a recognized Associated Professor and 4 students for a recognized Assistant Professor.

Read point number 4 on page 2 of [the guidelines for the Recognition of Fellow Programme of Self-Financing Autonomous
Management Institutions recognized by AICTE towards Equivalence to Ph.D Programme of Indian Universities](https://aiu.ac.in/documents/evaluation/AIU%20-%20Ph.D.%20Guidelines.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question, as this seems to be about requirements for "Fellow Programmes" to be considered equivalent to a PhD. I would not expect that this document has any implications for faculty at an Indian research university, right?

Comment: @xLeitix If you open the document and go to the section "Faculty and Research Guidance", point 4 suggests the answer.